Swift UI Tap Bar Border
I want to add a grey border to the top of the bottom tap bar in my iOS application. How can I do that with TabView and SwiftUI?
This is how my code looks like so far
struct MainView: View {
    init () {
        UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor(Color.theme.onSurfaceVariant)
    }
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView()
    }
}


struct NavigationView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            TabView {
                SearchScreen()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label(
                            NSLocalizedString(
                                "Search Nav",
                                value: "Search",
                                comment: "Label for Search Tab Item"
                            ),
                            systemImage: "magnifyingglass"
                        )
                    }
                TripsScreen()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label(
                            NSLocalizedString(
                                "Trips Nav",
                                value: "Trips",
                                comment: "Label for Trips Tab Item"
                            ),
                            systemImage: "suitcase"
                        )
                    }
                GuideScreen()
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("Guide")
                    }
                MapScreen()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label(
                            NSLocalizedString(
                                "Map Nav",
                                value: "Map",
                                comment: "Label for Map Tab Item"
                            ),
                            systemImage: "map"
                        )
                    }
                ProfileScreen()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label(
                            NSLocalizedString(
                                "Profile",
                                value: "Profile",
                                comment: "Label for Profile Tab Item"
                            ),
                            systemImage: "gear"
                        )
                    }
            }
            .accentColor(Color.theme.onSurface)
            .overlay {
                GuideImageView()
            }
        }
    }
}


struct GuideImageView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    print("Guide Button Tapped")
                }
                ) {
                    Image("GuideNavIcon") // Replace with your avatar image
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                        .padding(1)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.theme.stroke, lineWidth: 1))
                }
                .offset(y: -50)
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(height: 0)
        }
    }
}


You can create your own custom TabBar view. Here I am providing you with a similar design you need. You can take ideas from it and implement them in your way.
    struct CustomTabBar: View {
    @State var selectedItem: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if selectedItem == 0{
                TabView1()
            }else if selectedItem == 1{
                TabView2()
            }else if selectedItem == 2{
                TabView3()
            }
        }
        .overlay(
            BottomBar(selectedItem: $selectedItem),
            alignment: .bottom
        )
    }
}

struct TabView1: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.green
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}
struct TabView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.red
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}
struct TabView3: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color.blue
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}

struct BottomBar: View {
    @Binding var selectedItem: Int
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 50){
            Button {
                selectedItem = 0
            } label: {
                VStack{
                    Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                    Text("Home")
                }
                .padding(selectedItem == 0 ? 15 : 0)
                .background(
                    Circle()
                        .fill(.white)
                        .stroke(.black,
                                style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: selectedItem == 0 ? 2 : 0))
                )
            }
            
            
            Button {
                selectedItem = 1
            } label: {
                VStack{
                    Image(systemName: "gear")
                    Text("Settings")
                }
                .padding(selectedItem == 1 ? 15 : 0)
                .background(
                    Circle()
                        .fill(.white)
                        .stroke(.black,
                                style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: selectedItem == 1 ? 2 : 0))
                )

            }
            Button {
                selectedItem = 2
            } label: {
                VStack{
                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                    Text("Search")
                }
                .padding(selectedItem == 2 ? 15 : 0)
                .background(
                    Circle()
                        .fill(.white)
                        .stroke(.black,
                                style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: selectedItem == 2 ? 2 : 0))                )
            }
           
            
        }
        .padding()
        .padding(.horizontal)
//        .padding(.vertical, 10)
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .fill(Color.white)
                .shadow(radius: 8, x: 0, y: 5)
               
            
        )

    }
}


Here is the preview:

